# How to use the function inside the json_decode() using ci

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here i have one array, in this array i have one more array called **studentabsentId**,

```
public function admin_getabsentlist()
{
    $data = array(
    "schoolId" => $_POST['schoolName'],
    "classId" => $_POST['className'],
    "sectionId" => $_POST['sectionName'],
    "absentDate" => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['absentDate']))
    );

    $absentresponse= $this->Admin_attendance_model->admin_options_listdisplay($data);
    $optionsList = array();
    foreach($absentresponse as $hmres)
    {
        $hmparent['studentabsentId']=json_decode($hmres['studentAbsentId']);
        $hmparent['studentAbsentDate']=$hmres['studentAbsentDate'];
        array_push($optionsList,$hmparent);
    } 
    //echo $json = json_encode($optionsList);

    $return = array("status" => 1, "data" => $optionsList);
    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

> echo json_encode($return);

```
    {
  "status": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "studentabsentId": [
        "1"
      ],
      "studentAbsentDate": "2017-04-12"
    }
  ]
}
```

upto now its working fine,now what i want means,studentabsentId 1 means what is his name,suppose studentabsentId 2 means what is name, for that purpose i written the function called **getStudentnameById** in helper/custom_helper.php.

So in my for each loop i added one more line like this

> $hmparent['studentabsentName']=json_decode(getStudentnameById($hmres['studentAbsentId']));

But now i am getting the error of Undefined offset: 0,how can solve this error and , how to display the name

> custom_helper.php

```
    if ( ! function_exists('getStudentnameById')){
   function getStudentnameById($id){
       $ci =& get_instance();
       $ci->load->database();

       $ci->db->select('firstName');
       $ci->db->where('student_id', $id);
       $q = $ci->db->get('new_student')->result();
       return $q[0]->firstName; // particulart filed
   }
}
```

My updated code

> print_r($absentresponse);

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [absendId] => 2
            [studentAbsentId] => ["1"]
            [studentAbsentDate] => 2017-04-12
            [schoolId] => 2
            [classId] => 1
            [sectionId] => 1
            [reg_date] => 2017-04-13 01:01:14
            [created_by] => kanniyappan@g2evolution.co.in
            [status] => 0
        )

)
```

> Expected Results

```
    {
"status": 1,
"data": [
{
  "studentabsentId":"1"
  "studentabsentName":"Kani"
  "studentAbsentDate": "2017-04-12"
}
]
}
```

Comment: have you checked the output of json_decode(); ? if yes than for sure you get an idea.

Comment: i am not able to find the answer, can you please update your answer

Comment: @subikshanM just dump the json_decode  and see if returns array or object or has some error

Comment: 1. Print you json_decode output, analyze it, Also do check what happens when you write json_decode(array, true).

Comment: ***Undefined offset : 0*** point the array Index value is not found in array.. debug for your arrays which you make as well as which are return from the function. this will help more to resolve the issue.

Comment: remove json_decode form ***$hmparent['studentabsentId']=json_decode($hmres['studentAbsentId']);*** Also from ***$hmparent['studentabsentName']=json_decode(getStudentnameById($hmres['studentAbsentId']));***

Comment: print the final array.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a free crowd sourced code generator.

Answer (score 0):

Your getStudentnameById returns a string supposedly, so why are you doing a json_decode on top of that.    `$hmparent['studentabsentName']=json_decode(getStudentnameById($hmres['studentAbsentId']));`

Also check the return by that function. You should be able to debug this kind of code if you turned on your error_reporting which tells you the line at which error occurred, then var_dump all the variables that's relevant to it.